# What does Page() method in Razor Pages OnPost method do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

ASP NET CORE 2
I have following page model code

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IItemService _itemService;
    public ItemCreateViewModel ItemModel { get; set; }

    public CreateModel(IItemService itemService)
    {
        _itemService = itemService;
    }
    // all related data downloaded from db, so all rendered correctly
    public async Task OnGet(ItemCreateViewModel itemModel)
    {
        ItemModel = await _itemService.GetCreateViewModel();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(ItemCreateViewModel itemModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        var item = _itemService.CreateItem(itemModel);
        var image = await ImagesController.ProcessFormImage(itemModel.ImageUpload.UploadPhoto, item.Id, ModelState);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //trouble is somewhere here 
            return Page();
        }
        await _itemService.SaveItemImage(image);
        _itemService.CreateItem(itemModel);
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

When I try to post wrong image, !ModelState.IsValid yeilds true and Page() invoked. I get
`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` in `Model.ItemModel.Categories` where `Categories` is one of serveral select lists normally downloaded from db by _itemService.GetCreateViewModel().
I do not understand what happens at `Page()`. Why isn't old data from form used? How can I rerender page with validation errors (I have `asp-validation-for` in cshtml)? I tried `this.ItemModel = itemModel`, and I get no more Null reference, but do not see any validation errors, and previous select lists values not saved.

Comment: it is the same as returning `View()` in normal MVC

Comment: I believe the semantics are similar to what you had to do before in the controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return Page` is the same as calling `return View()` in the normal MVC Controller action.

> When the submitted form has validation errors (that are passed to the server), the `OnPostAsync` handler method calls the `Page` helper method. `Page` returns an instance of `PageResult`. Returning `Page` is similar to how actions in controllers return `View`. `PageResult` is the default return type for a handler method. A handler method that returns `void` renders the page.

Update the page model property to allow the view to bind to the model.

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel {
    private readonly IItemService _itemService;

    public CreateModel(IItemService itemService) {
        _itemService = itemService;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public ItemCreateViewModel ItemModel { get; set; }

    // all related data downloaded from db, so all rendered correctly
    public  async Task<IActionResult>  OnGetAsync() {
        ItemModel = await _itemService.GetCreateViewModel();
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return Page();
        }
        var item = _itemService.CreateItem(ItemModel);
        var image = await ImagesController.ProcessFormImage(ItemModel.ImageUpload.UploadPhoto, item.Id, ModelState);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {                
            return Page();
        }

        await _itemService.SaveItemImage(image);
        _itemService.CreateItem(ItemModel);
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Reference [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: finally it got clearer to me what happens. I have to read the basics properly. thank you.